# CSS Transform with % convert from px dont work

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;background:#65C6BB;position:absolute;transform: translate(20px,0px);">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to convert the CSS property ' transform ' to percentage.

I using the rule : `(100 / window.innerWidth) *pixels`

Just doing it my result to a Window Width of 1920 is 1.0416666666666667

If I replace it in the property CSS transform to 
`transform: translate(1.0416666666666667%,0px);`

The div will not stay in the same position. I've tried using window.document.body.offsetWidth but don't works too.

PS: with width and height is working.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Transform using % moves the element with respect to element's size and not its parent's size. The formula should be `(100 / element.offsetWidth) * pixels`